# Acumatica - Detail Record Not using Auto-Numbered Field of Master Record

Tags: c#, asp.net, acumatica, master-detail

I have a maintenance form in Acumatica 2020R2 that has a master-detail relationship between a form and two tab items that contain grids. I have the ID of the form auto-numbering, and the detail records use this ID with the PXParentAttribute. The form auto-numbers and saves to the database with the correct ID, but the detail records are saving to the database with the initial placeholder **<*NEW*>** instead of the auto-number.

Here are the DAC fields that the form uses:

```
        #region VendorRebateID
        [PXDBString(15, IsKey = true, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = ">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC")]
        [PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.NullOrBlank)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Vendor Rebate Code", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
        [AutoNumber(typeof(APVendorRebateSetup.numberingID), typeof(AccessInfo.businessDate))]
        [PXSelector(typeof(Search<APVendorRebate.vendorRebateID>))]
        public virtual string VendorRebateID { get; set; }
        public abstract class vendorRebateID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<vendorRebateID> { }
        #endregion

        #region Description
        [PXDBString(256, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Description")]
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
        public abstract class description : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<description> { }
        #endregion

        #region VendorID
        [Vendor]
        [PXDefault]
        [PXParent(typeof(Select<Vendor, Where<Vendor.bAccountID, Equal<Current<APVendorPrice.vendorID>>>>))]
        public virtual int? VendorID { get; set; }
        public abstract class vendorID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<vendorID> { }
        #endregion

        #region CuryID
        [PXDBString(5)]
        [PXDefault(typeof(Search<PX.Objects.GL.Company.baseCuryID>))]
        [PXSelector(typeof(Currency.curyID), CacheGlobal = true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Currency", Required = false, Visible = false, Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]
        public virtual string CuryID { get; set; }
        public abstract class curyID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<curyID> { }
        #endregion

        #region EffectiveDate
        [PXDefault(typeof(AccessInfo.businessDate), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
        [PXDBDate()]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Effective Date", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]
        public virtual DateTime? EffectiveDate { get; set; }
        public abstract class effectiveDate : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDateTime.Field<effectiveDate> { }
        #endregion

        #region ExpirationDate
        [PXDBDate()]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Expiration Date", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]
        public virtual DateTime? ExpirationDate { get; set; }
        public abstract class expirationDate : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDateTime.Field<expirationDate> { }
        #endregion
```

Here are the DAC fields that one of the grids uses:

```
        #region VendorRebateID
        [PXDBString(15, IsKey = true, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
        [PXDefault(typeof(APVendorRebate.vendorRebateID))]
        [PXParent(typeof(SelectFrom<APVendorRebate>.
            Where<APVendorRebate.vendorRebateID.IsEqual<APVendorRebateCustomer.vendorRebateID.FromCurrent>>))]
        public virtual string VendorRebateID { get; set; }
        public abstract class vendorRebateID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<vendorRebateID> { }
        #endregion

        #region CustomerID
        [PX.Objects.AR.Customer(DescriptionField = typeof(PX.Objects.AR.Customer.acctName), IsKey = true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Customer")]
        public virtual int? CustomerID { get; set; }
        public abstract class customerID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<customerID> { }
        #endregion
```

Here are the DAC fields that the other grid uses:

```
        #region VendorRebateID
        [PXDBString(15, IsKey = true, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
        [PXDefault(typeof(APVendorRebate.vendorRebateID))]
        [PXParent(typeof(SelectFrom<APVendorRebate>.
            Where<APVendorRebate.vendorRebateID.IsEqual<APVendorRebateInventoryItem.vendorRebateID.FromCurrent>>))]
        public virtual string VendorRebateID { get; set; }
        public abstract class vendorRebateID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<vendorRebateID> { }
        #endregion

        #region InventoryID
        [APCrossItem(BAccountField = typeof(APVendorRebate.vendorID), IsKey = true, WarningOnNonUniqueSubstitution = true)]
        [PXParent(typeof(Select<InventoryItem, Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Current<APVendorPrice.inventoryID>>>>))]
        public virtual int? InventoryID { get; set; }
        public abstract class inventoryID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<inventoryID> { }
        #endregion

        #region AlternateID
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Alternate ID")]
        [PXDBString(50, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
        public virtual string AlternateID { get; set; }
        public abstract class alternateID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<alternateID> { }
        #endregion

        #region UOM
        [PXDefault(typeof(Search<InventoryItem.purchaseUnit, Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Current<APVendorPrice.inventoryID>>>>))]
        [INUnit(typeof(APVendorPrice.inventoryID))]
        [PXFormula(typeof(Selector<APVendorPrice.inventoryID, InventoryItem.purchaseUnit>))]
        public virtual string UOM { get; set; }
        public abstract class uOM : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<uOM> { }
        #endregion

        #region "Rebate Selling Price"
        [PXDBPriceCost]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Selling Price", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]
        public virtual decimal? SellingPrice { get; set; }
        public abstract class sellingPrice : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDecimal.Field<sellingPrice> { }
        #endregion

        #region RebatePrice
        [PXDBPriceCost]
        [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Rebate Price", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]
        public virtual decimal? RebatePrice { get; set; }
        public abstract class rebatePrice : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDecimal.Field<rebatePrice> { }
        #endregion

        #region VendorPrice
        [PXPriceCost]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Vendor Price", Enabled = false)]
        [PXDependsOnFields(typeof(APVendorRebate.vendorID), typeof(APVendorRebateInventoryItem.inventoryID), typeof(APVendorRebate.effectiveDate), typeof(APVendorRebate.expirationDate))]
        [LatestVendorPrice]
        public virtual decimal? VendorPrice { get; set; }
        public abstract class vendorPrice : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDecimal.Field<vendorPrice> { }
        #endregion

        #region BreakQty
        [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
        [PXDBQuantity(MinValue = 0)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Break Qty", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]
        public virtual decimal? BreakQty { get; set; }
        public abstract class breakQty : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDecimal.Field<breakQty> { }
        #endregion

        #region SiteID
        [NullableSite]
        public virtual int? SiteID { get; set; }
        public abstract class siteID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDecimal.Field<siteID> { }
        #endregion
```

Here is the ASPX code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/FormView.master" AutoEventWireup="true" ValidateRequest="false" CodeFile="AP209900.aspx.cs" Inherits="Page_AP209900" Title="Untitled Page" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPages/FormView.master" %>

<asp:Content ID="cont1" ContentPlaceHolderID="phDS" Runat="Server">
  <px:PXDataSource Height="" ID="ds" runat="server" Visible="True" Width="100%"
        TypeName="APVendorRebates.APVendorRebateMaint"
        PrimaryView="Rebates"
        >
    <CallbackCommands>

    </CallbackCommands>
  </px:PXDataSource>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="cont2" ContentPlaceHolderID="phF" Runat="Server">
  <px:PXFormView AllowCollapse="false" Height="" ID="form" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" DataMember="Rebates" Width="100%" AllowAutoHide="false">
    <Template>
      <px:PXLayoutRule runat="server" ID="PXLayoutRule1" StartRow="True" ></px:PXLayoutRule>
      <px:PXLayoutRule ControlSize="XM" StartGroup="False" SuppressLabel="False" LabelsWidth="SM" runat="server" ID="CstPXLayoutRule1" StartColumn="True" ></px:PXLayoutRule>
      <px:PXSelector CommitChanges="True" runat="server" ID="CstPXSelector6" DataField="VendorRebateID" >
        <GridProperties>
          <Layout BorderMode="NotSet" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" ></Layout></GridProperties></px:PXSelector>
      <px:PXSegmentMask CommitChanges="True" runat="server" ID="CstPXSegmentMask4" DataField="VendorID" ></px:PXSegmentMask>
      <px:PXLayoutRule runat="server" ID="CstLayoutRule21" ColumnSpan="2" ></px:PXLayoutRule>
      <px:PXTextEdit runat="server" ID="CstPXTextEdit10" DataField="Description" ></px:PXTextEdit>
      <px:PXLayoutRule StartRow="False" ControlSize="SM" StartGroup="False" SuppressLabel="False" LabelsWidth="SM" runat="server" ID="CstPXLayoutRule2" StartColumn="True" ></px:PXLayoutRule>
      <px:PXDateTimeEdit CommitChanges="True" runat="server" ID="CstPXDateTimeEdit7" DataField="EffectiveDate" ></px:PXDateTimeEdit>
      <px:PXDateTimeEdit CommitChanges="True" runat="server" ID="CstPXDateTimeEdit8" DataField="ExpirationDate" ></px:PXDateTimeEdit></Template>
    <AutoSize Container="Parent" Enabled="False" MinHeight="140" ></AutoSize>
  </px:PXFormView>
  <px:PXTab Height="" runat="server" ID="CstPXTab14">
    <Items>
      <px:PXTabItem RepaintOnDemand="False" BindingContext="form" Text="Inventory Items" >
        <Template>
          <px:PXGrid SyncPosition="False" Width="100%" runat="server" ID="CstPXGrid15" SkinID="Details">
            <Levels>
              <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="InventoryItems" >
                <Columns>
                  <px:PXGridColumn CommitChanges="True" DataField="InventoryID" Width="70" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                  <px:PXGridColumn DataField="InventoryID_description" Width="280" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                  <px:PXGridColumn DataField="AlternateID" Width="180" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                  <px:PXGridColumn DataField="UOM" Width="72" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                  <px:PXGridColumn DataField="SellingPrice" Width="100" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                  <px:PXGridColumn DataField="RebatePrice" Width="100" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                  <px:PXGridColumn DataField="VendorPrice" Width="100" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                  <px:PXGridColumn DataField="BreakQty" Width="100" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                  <px:PXGridColumn DataField="SiteID" Width="140" ></px:PXGridColumn></Columns>
                <RowTemplate></RowTemplate></px:PXGridLevel></Levels>
            <AutoSize Enabled="True" ></AutoSize>
            <Mode InitNewRow="True" ></Mode></px:PXGrid></Template></px:PXTabItem>
      <px:PXTabItem RepaintOnDemand="False" BindingContext="form" Text="Customers" >
        <Template>
          <px:PXGrid SyncPosition="False" runat="server" ID="CstPXGrid16" Width="100%" SkinID="Details">
            <Levels>
              <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="Customers" >
                <Columns>
                  <px:PXGridColumn DataField="CustomerID" Width="140" CommitChanges="True" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                  <px:PXGridColumn DataField="CustomerID_description" Width="280" ></px:PXGridColumn></Columns>
                <RowTemplate></RowTemplate></px:PXGridLevel></Levels>
            <AutoSize Enabled="True" ></AutoSize>
            <Mode InitNewRow="True" ></Mode></px:PXGrid></Template></px:PXTabItem></Items>
    <AutoSize Enabled="True" />
    <AutoSize MinHeight="180" />
    <AutoSize Container="Window" /></px:PXTab></asp:Content>
```

Here is how the records are being inserted into the database:

[image]

I'm fairly new to Acumatica, and I based this code on the instructions in the T210 training course. I followed the steps very carefully, and I'm not sure why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the child DAC's, the PXDefault should be PXDBDefault.  This was a common problem for me when I got started.  The difference for PXDBDefault is that it is "use to assign a value from the auto-generated key field".

Here is a very basic example of the child DAC field using PXDBDefault.  The master table in this example is XXDocument, and the child table is XXLine.  The key field is myID.

```
#region MyID
[PXDBInt(IsKey = true)]
[PXDBDefault(typeof(XXDocument.myID))]
[PXParent(
    typeof(Select<XXDocument,
            Where<XXDocument.myID,
            Equal<Current<XXLine.myID>>>>)
    )]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = Messages.FldMyID)]
public virtual int? MyID { get; set; }
public abstract class myID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<myID> { }
#endregion
```

Worth noting, I use an ID vs CD set of fields.  The parent ID is an Identity field in the database, and the Autonumber field is a CD field.  I suspect this also is contributing to your issue, and as such, my example above may not fit directly as you are attempting it.  I find it very important to use the integer identity field for key fields and my auto-numbers as a CD (code) field as it is much cleaner as a data structure and more efficient for the database to store/retrieve integer over strings.  Also, you can change the CD value without impacting the table relationships (similar to how it is handled in InventoryItem).

The parent table's ID/CD fields are shown below:

```
#region MyID
[PXDBIdentity]
public virtual int? MyID { get; set; }
public abstract class myID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<myID> { }
#endregion

#region MyCD
[PXDBString(15, IsKey = true, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
[PXDefault]
[AutoNumber(typeof(XXSetup.myNumberingID), typeof(AccessInfo.businessDate))]
[PXSelector(
    typeof(MyDocument.myCD),
    typeof(MyDocument.myCD),
    typeof(MyDocument.descr)
    )]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = Messages.FldMyCD, Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
public virtual string MyCD { get; set; }
public abstract class myCD : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<myCD> { }
#endregion
```